# python element to mongo-db needs to be converted to a dict (not an array anymore)

Tags: python, arrays, string, dictionary, mongoengine

I'm trying to update a particular nested value in my mongodb by executing this part of code in python:

`put_list = Lists.objects(id=list_id,sublist__subListCreator=user).update_one(set__sublist__S=sublistvalue)`

My document is stored in mongo like this and I would like to replace the part that starts with "subListCreator": "jan" with my put-call:

```
   "_id": {
      "$oid": "62019f5a20c7b8940aeff622"
   },
   "chapters": "",
   "listTitle": "Awesome dogs",
   "sublist": [
      {
         "subListCreator": "lotte",
         "subListAdded": {
            "$date": {
               "$numberLong": "1645139589508"
            }
         },
         "subListLastChanged": {
            "$date": {
               "$numberLong": "1645139600958"
            }
         },
         "item": [
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "1"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "3"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Maddie"
            },
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "2"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "2"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Kafka"
            },
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "3"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "1"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Rika"
            },
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "4"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "1"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Daisy"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "subListCreator": "jan",
         "subListAdded": {
            "$date": {
               "$numberLong": "1645141622177"
            }
         },
         "item": [
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "1"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "3"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Maddie typo"
            },
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "2"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "2"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Kafka"
            },
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "3"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "1"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Rika"
            },
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "4"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "1"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Daisy"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

However when I execute the first line above, the updated document looks as follows:

```
   "_id": {
      "$oid": "62019f5a20c7b8940aeff622"
   },
   "chapters": "",
   "listTitle": "Awesome dogs",
   "sublist": [
      {
         "subListCreator": "lotte",
         "subListAdded": {
            "$date": {
               "$numberLong": "1645139589508"
            }
         },
         "subListLastChanged": {
            "$date": {
               "$numberLong": "1645139600958"
            }
         },
         "item": [
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "1"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "3"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Maddie"
            },
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "2"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "2"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Kafka"
            },
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "3"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "1"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Rika"
            },
            {
               "positionId": {
                  "$numberInt": "4"
               },
               "itemScore": {
                  "$numberInt": "1"
               },
               "itemTitle": "Daisy"
            }
         ]
      },
      [
         {
            "subListCreator": "jan",
            "subListAdded": {
               "$date": {
                  "$numberLong": "1645142213522"
               }
            },
            "subListLastChanged": {
               "$date": {
                  "$numberLong": "1645142217623"
               }
            },
            "item": [
               {
                  "positionId": {
                     "$numberInt": "1"
                  },
                  "itemScore": {
                     "$numberInt": "3"
                  },
                  "itemTitle": "Maddie"
               },
               {
                  "positionId": {
                     "$numberInt": "2"
                  },
                  "itemScore": {
                     "$numberInt": "2"
                  },
                  "itemTitle": "Kafka"
               },
               {
                  "positionId": {
                     "$numberInt": "3"
                  },
                  "itemScore": {
                     "$numberInt": "1"
                  },
                  "itemTitle": "Rika"
               },
               {
                  "positionId": {
                     "$numberInt": "4"
                  },
                  "itemScore": {
                     "$numberInt": "1"
                  },
                  "itemTitle": "Daisy"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Which is almost the same except for the fact that there are now brackets around my updated sublist. Making it an array with an object in it instead of just an object in my Mongo database.

The way I tried to workaround this is in the python code go for:

```
   newsublistvalue = str(sublistvalue)[1:-1] 
    print(newsublistvalue)
```

However, this doesn't work as well, because now my error is:

raise ValueError(  ValueError: The source SON object needs to be of type 'dict' but a '<class 'str'>' was found

Can somebody help me to deliver a proper dict that does not have the brackets around so I can finalize this PUT api ?

This is the code used for the PUT api part:

```
   @jwt_required()
    def put(self) -> Response:
        data = request.get_json()
        list_id = data['id']
        print(list_id)
        output = Users.objects.get(id=get_jwt_identity())
        user = output['username']
        print(user)
        for sublist in data['sublist']:
            if sublist['subListCreator'] == user:
                sublist['subListLastChanged'] = datetime.datetime.now()
                for i,item in enumerate(sublist['item']):
                    item['positionId'] = i + 1
                    if item['positionId'] == 1:
                        item['itemScore'] = 3
                    else:
                        if item['positionId'] == 2:
                            item['itemScore'] = 2
                        else:
                            item['itemScore'] = 1
        sublistvalue = data['sublist']
        print(sublistvalue) 
        # newsublistvalue = str(sublistvalue)[1:-1] 
        # print(newsublistvalue) 
        put_list = Lists.objects(id=list_id, sublist__subListCreator=user).update_one(set__sublist__S=sublistvalue)
        lists = jsonify({'result': put_list})
        return lists
```

And this is what I send in the PUT request:

```
{
   "listTitle": "Awesome dogs",
   "id": "62019f5a20c7b8940aeff622",
   "chapters": "",
   "sublist": [
      {
         "subListCreator": "jan",
         "item": [
            {
               "itemTitle": "Maddie",
               "itemContext": null
            },
            {
               "itemTitle": "Kafka",
               "itemContext": null
            },
            {
               "itemTitle": "Rika",
               "itemContext": null
            },
            {
               "itemTitle": "Daisy",
               "itemContext": null
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks a lot for having a look! I hope this is just a simple one, it feels like I'm not that far from having the right outcome.